# How to pass evaluated values to a custom element directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom element directive with the following template:

```html
<div>
   <input value="{{dataFromRootScope}}" />
</div>
```

And definition:

```js
dirModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',            
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/directives/myDirective.html'     
        };
    }
);
```

I would like to use the directive as shown below:

```html
<my-directive my-value="{{dataFromScope}}"></my-directive>
```

i.e. I want to use the evaluated `dataFromScope` value inside my custom directive as `dataFromRootScope`. How can I reach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the '@' sign :

```
dirModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: { myValue: '@' },
        restrict: 'E',            
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/directives/myDirective.html'     
    };
});
```

The '@' sign binds the evaluated value of the DOM attribute to the directive.

You can then use the directive as you asked :

```
<my-directive my-value="{{dataFromScope}}"></my-directive>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use isolated scope two-way binding:

```
dirModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '=myValue'
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/directives/myDirective.html'
    };
});
```

Where directive template is

```
<div>
   <input ng-model="model" />
</div>
```

and usage is

```
<my-directive my-value="dataFromScope"></my-directive>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Npiq2hCO4tQHmakG4IAe?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works perfect, but the `@` sign is closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: `=` ensures two-way binding for the variable you are accessing

Comment: @NLN probably OP doesn't need it.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use the evaluated dataFromScope value inside my custom
>   directive as dataFromRootScope. How can I reach this?

Well you have two options to achieve this.

**Option-1**: Create an isolated scope for your directive

This way, you would need to assign value of `dataFromRootScope` from myValue. The `=` operator ensures two-way binding.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{
               dataFromRootScope: '=myValue'
            },
            templateUrl: 'myDirective.html'
        };
    }
);
```

'dataFromScope' will not be available in myDirective because it has isolated scope. You can access it via `dataFromRootScope`(see how its getting its value from `myValue`)

```
<div>
   <input value="{{dataFromRootScope}}" />
</div>
```

[Demo-1](http://plnkr.co/edit/QTPvVY9qk5cLVEcs4SgI?p=preview)

**Option-2**: Enjoy shared scope.

In this case, you dont need to create an isolated scope. You can simply use `dataFromScope` in your directive template OR, if you really want to access it as `dataFromRootScope` in your template, simply assign it in your link function.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'myDirective.html',
            link:function(scope,ele,attr){
              scope.dataFromRootScope = scope.dataFromScope
            }
        };
    }
);

<div>
   <input value="{{dataFromRootScope}}" />
</div>
```

[Demo-2](http://plnkr.co/edit/PuQJDHPu6TtpyjYzLFKv?p=preview)